# Appearance of ~$ files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

There are many hidden files starting with ~$"file name". Nearly every word, excel or PowerPoint have a combined ~$ file. This file appears when I open the word, excel or PowerPoint file then disappear after closing the office file. But when I searched for office file I found many hidden ~$ files.
1- I need to know the reason behind the existence of these hidden files even after I closed the office file.
2- How can I delete all these files

Comment: If the program does not close properly, it can leave these files behind.  I have bat files that I run which remove many different types of backup files.  Or you can try a program like CCleaner (its free).

Comment: These files are temproary files, which are created to temporarily store information so that memory can be freed up for other purposes or act as a safe net to prevent data loss while the Office apps perform certain functions.

Answer (score 3):

Files that begin with ~$ are temporary files from Microsoft Office.

They are used to identify who has opened a file such that when another user opens that file, they get a prompt who else is working in the file.

By default, these files should automatically go away when the other user closes the file. In rare occasions these files may remain behind. For example, if the user that had the file open has a crash and word/excel did not terminate normally. Often these users get a message that they can recover these files upon opening word/excel. Recovering these files does not depend on the existence of the ~$ file though.

Another option for these files to remain is if the user loses network connection and then closes word/excel. For example, the user works on a laptop, opens a file, closes the lid of the laptop to go home, at home opens the lid and then closes the file.

Files that remain can be safely deleted. Files that are created when they are actually in use will also become read-only.

For that reason, it is safe to attempt to delete these ~$ files, but keep in mind, that they are part of office, and that it is normal that they are there. They are hidden by default, and you will only see them if you have show hidden files enabled.